# React.js error onupdtaing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to update fields when drugid is given.But when i select drugid as 1 and update button is clicked it says'localhost:8081/drug/1' not found.In mongodb db there is auto generated _id column as well.When i use postman and try to update using mongo _id it works.How to update it through my drugid.Please help

UpdateDrugHandler .jsx

'use strict';

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import axios from 'axios';
   import UpdateDrugController from '../Controllers/UpdateDrugController';
   import PropTypes            from 'prop-types';


export default class UpdateDrugHandler extends Component {
// static get propTypes() {
//     return {
//         user: PropTypes.object
//     }
// }
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
//   this.user = this.props.user;

  this.state = {
     drugs: []
  };
  this.updateDrug = this.updateDrug.bind(this);
 }  
   updateDrug(drugid,drugname,drugqty,remark,drugtype,
   drugcreatedate,drugdosage,drugcreatedby,drugexpiration,drugprice){
   axios.put(`http://localhost:8081/drug/` + drugid ,{
    drugid:drugid,
    drugname:drugname,
    drugqty:drugqty,
    remark:remark,
    drugtype:drugtype,
    drugcreatedate:drugcreatedate,
    drugdosage:drugdosage,
    drugcreatedby:drugcreatedby,
    drugexpiration:drugexpiration,
    drugprice:drugprice


}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
})
 }
 render() {
  return <div>
       <UpdateDrugController
            updateDrug={this.updateDrug}
        />
  </div>
}
 }
```

UpdateDrugController.jsx

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class UpdateDrugController extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        users: []
    }
        this.getAllUsers();

}

    onSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateDrug(
        this.drugid.value,
        this.drugname.value,
        this.drugqty.value,
        this.remark.value,
        this.drugtype.value,
        this.drugcreatedate.value,
        this.drugdosage.value,
        this.drugcreatedby.value,
        this.drugexpiration.value,
        this.drugprice.value,

    );
    this.drugid.value='';
    this.drugname.value='';
    this.drugqty.value='';
    this.remark.value='';
    this.drugtype.value='';
    this.drugcreatedate.value='';
    this.drugdosage.value='';
    this.drugcreatedby.value='';
    this.drugexpiration.value='';
    this.drugprice.value='';

   }

getAllUsers() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/drug`).then(res => {
        this.setState({
            users: res.data.data || res.data
        });
    })
}

render() {
    return <div>
        <div class="ui grid">
 <div class="three column row">
<div class="column"></div>


        <div class="ui icon message">
        <i class="inbox icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">
            xxx
            </div>
            <p>Get the best news in your e-mail every day.</p>
        </div>
        </div>


        <form class="ui tiny form">
        <div class="ui compact message">
        <p>New Drugs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="DrugID" ref={drugid=>this.drugid=drugid}/></div>
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Drug Name" ref={drugname=>this.drugname=drugname}/></div>              
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Quantity" ref={drugqty=>this.drugqty=drugqty}/></div>              
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="10" placeholder="Remark" ref={remark=>this.remark=remark}/></div>              
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Drug Type" ref={drugtype=>this.drugtype=drugtype}/></div>              
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Created Date" ref={drugcreatedate=>this.drugcreatedate=drugcreatedate}/></div>              
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Drug Dosage" ref={drugdosage=>this.drugdosage=drugdosage}/></div>
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Drug Created" ref={drugcreatedby=>this.drugcreatedby=drugcreatedby}/></div>
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Drug Expiration" ref={drugexpiration=>this.drugexpiration=drugexpiration}/></div>
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><input maxlength="6" placeholder="Drug Price" ref={drugprice=>this.drugprice=drugprice}/></div>
        <div class="field"><label>First Name</label><button  class="ui primary button" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Update </button></div>
        </form>


        <div class="column">ssssssssssss</div>
        <div class="column">ssssssssssssssc</div>
        </div>
        </div>     

        </div>

}
}
```

Comment: I am using a new browser. am I wrong in defining drugs?

Comment: Object {data: "Drug Added", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}
config
:
Object
data
:
"Drug Added"
headers
:
Object
request
:
XMLHttpRequest
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
__proto__
:
Object

Answer (score 0):

Check what http://localhost:8081/drug is returning. You are setting `drugs` to what comes back from that call. Looking at the error you are getting, it is probably not returning an array, in which case, `drugs` has no function `map`.

Comment: This what postman gives for above url edited on the code.plz check

Answer (score 0):

Update your About.jsx code with this code

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Home extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         drugs: []
      };
   }

   componentWillMount() {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/drug`).then(res => {
         const drugs = res.data;
         this.setState({ drugs });
         console.log(drugs);

      })
   }

   render() {
      return <div>
         <h2>This is the available Drug list</h2>
         <div>
            {
               this.state.drugs && this.state.drugs.map(drug =>
                  <div>
                     <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>DrugID:{drug.drugid}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Drug Name:{drug.drugname}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Quantity:{drug.drugqty}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Remark:{drug.remark}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Drug Type:{drug.drugtype}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Created Date:{drug.drugcreatedate}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Drug Dosage:{drug.drugdosage}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Drug Created By:{drug.drugcreatedby}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Drug Expiration:{drug.drugexpiration}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Drug Price:{drug.drugprice}</span></td>
                           <td><span key={drug._id}>Danger Level:{drug.dangerlevel}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               )
            }
         </div>
      </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked.         this.setState({ drugs:drugs.data });